# What is the correct syntax for specifying an array of characters as a function parameter?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, parameter-passing

What is the correct syntax for specifying an array of characters as one of the parameters of a function?

I don't know if I am stressed and unable to find the error or because i have been away from C for a while. I just cannot spot the error. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void reverseWord(int len, char[] str, int index)
{
    int start, end;
    char temp;
    start = index - len;
    end = index - 1;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        temp = str[start];
        str[start] = str[end];
        str[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end --;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i,j=0, len;
    int tmp = 0;
    char str[]="i am a loser";
    char word[]= " ";
    len = strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    { 
        if(str[i] == ' ')
        {
            tmp = strlen(word);
            if(tmp != 0)
            {    
                 reverseWord(tmp , str ,i);
                 j = 0; <<ERROR PRONE LINE>>
            }
        }
       else
           word[j++]=str[i];
    }

    printf ("final string = %s",str); 
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘str’ on line marked above
```

Comment: Which line is "marked"? (the error message says a line is marked)

Comment: this is about as `too localized` as it gets ...

Comment: @Nate I have clearly written in the code as `<<ERROR PRONE LINE>>`

Comment: @appyg where is the function `reverseWord` declared and defined? If you fix all these issues, the linker will complain about the missing definition of this function.

Comment: May be unrelated, but you defined word as `char word[]= " ";`, which unless I'm mistaken means it is a character array with one element. But then in your for loop you have `word[j++]=str[i];`, which means you could potentially have a buffer overrun (I think?).

Comment: @Nate I tried fixing that my trying it as word[100]. Still the same error

Comment: `void reverseWord(int len, char[] str, int index)` must be re-written as `void reverseWord(int len, char str[], int index)`.

Comment: This is a valid question. The question has been generalized with suitable edits. Please re-open!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the definition of `str` in `reverseWord` function. Instead of `char[] str`, if you modify the same to `char* str`, your compilation will be successful.

If you wish to use the `[]` concept, then one potential solution could be to define a new data type as

```
typedef char myArrStr[100];
```

which defines `myArrStr` to be an 100 element character array.

In the function definition of `reverseWord`, you could modify the definition to

```
void reverseWord(int len, myArrStr str, int index)
```

The definition of `str` could be modified as

```
myArrStr str = "i am a winner"; // Changed your message :-)
```

With these updates, your code should just work fine.

Comment: @Ganesh You may reopen the question (since your repute is > 3000) if you believe the concern has been addressed with the edits I've made.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the closing brace `}` for the line `if(str[i] == ' ')`

Comment: Sorry for misleading but that was a typing mistake. I have corrected that in the question. This means this is actually not the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

you forgot a closing brace

```
if(str[i] == ' ')
{
            tmp = strlen(word);
            if(tmp != 0)
            {    
                 reverseWord(tmp , str ,i);
                 j = 0; <<ERROR PRONE LINE>>
            }
}
else
{
           word[j++]=str[i];
}
```

Comment: I fixed that typing error on stackoverflow. But there still exists the real error :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing closing brace that should be right above the `else` statement.

Also, it's a very good idea to always have braces surrounding the contents of an `if` or `else` statement, because if you end up adding another line at a later time only the one directly below the `if` or `else` statement will be executed (this error can be really difficult to spot).

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int i,j=0, len;
    int tmp = 0;
    char str[]="i am a loser";
    char word[]= " ";
    len = strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    { 
        if(str[i] == ' ')
        {
            tmp = strlen(word);
            if(tmp != 0)
            {    
                 reverseWord(tmp , str ,i);
                 j = 0; <<ERROR PRONE LINE>>
            }
        }
       else
       {
           word[j++]=str[i];
       }
    }

    printf ("final string = %s",str); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading. I initially made a typing mistake. That is not the error

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `reverseWord` function defined? You will need to include the file it is defined in:

`#include "otherfile.h"`

If the function is defined in the same file you can move the `reverseWord` function above main.

Comment: please take a look at the updated code